# No named parameter with the name 'findProxy'

Tags: flutter, dependencies

when i run my codes it gives this error

```
    Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
: Error: No named parameter with the name 'findProxy'.
../…/src/http.dart:60
          findProxy: findProxy,
          ^^^^^^^^^
: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
../…/html/http_request_html.dart:13
  HttpRequestImpl({
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Failed to compile application.
Exited (sigterm)
```

anyone knows what is the problem..?

thanks

Comment: It will be easy to understand if you will add full code